# Error al conectar con MongoDB usando Mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy desarollando una api para hacer sing-in / sing-up con NodeJS usando mongoose, express, jwt. El servidor arranca, pero estoy teniendo el drama para conectar a la DB y no encuentro el problema, creo que estoy exportando bien la conexion.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte el todo el código de la conexión, el mensaje de error se puede ver en la imágen, pero sin código no se puede hacer mucho.Revisa [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Si es cierto ! Pense que lo habia puesto, la idea era ponerlo y complementar con la imagen. 
Dato para la proxima :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro, connectWithMongo no lo estas retornado como una función. Tu código quedaría así.

```
const connectWithMongo = () => {
  mongoose.connect(
    `${mongoURL}`,
    { useFindAndModify: false },
    (err, db) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("conectando a mongo");
    }
  );
};
```

te recomiendo leer la documentación de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/)